# Ionic cordova prepare ios throws an error "An error occurred while running subprocess cordova."

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

IONIF INFO:
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
@angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.3
native-run  : 0.2.9

ERROR:

iOS project created with cordova-ios@5.1.1
Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Tried using ionic cordova resources

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a file missing, is this referenced in your config file?

Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png

You will need to correct the path or it won't compile.

Comment: Yes it is in the config file:
<icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />

Comment: i tried  ionic cordova resources to add resources

Answer (score -1):

I added manually the resources file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).